# Default flash builder mobile theme boring - how to get android holo design working

Tags: android, apache-flex, themes, flash-builder

Does anyone know how to get the Google Android holo design instead of the default mobile theme (skin) into Flash Builder 4.6

The holo skin:

http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

How could I style buttons, checkboxes and input fields more up to date. The style of the components in the default mobile theme in the Falsh Builder is a bit boring.

Will be thankful for any tips, links and suggestions.

Ge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [Custom Skin(s)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c698e85712b3011fe73-7fff.html) for your project that mimics/applies the Halo design.